# Remove all occurences of several characters from a string

Tags: c#, string, coding-style

So I have a string that has numbers, letters and symbols in it like this:

```
AD 123 (+45) AS 6.7(+8%)
```

and I want all of the numbers in a `List<double>`. To do this I first want to remove all occurences of `'(', ')', '+'` and `'%'`. 
My current approach is the `string.Replace()` method but that looks kind of dirty:

```
stats = stats.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("%", "").Replace("+", "");
```

Any alternative ideas? I don't want to just write code that works, I want it to be elegant.

Comment: What exactly are the results you expect?  Do you want for example a list containing the number 123, 45, 6.7, and 8?

Comment: @Wilsu can you show us what the expected outcome should be based on `Habib` answer, I think this is what you are perhaps looking for..

Comment: I want exactly what I said: I want all of the numbers in a List of type double. I used the code above to remove the symbols mentioned and then split the string at the spaces and iterated the array I got. For every item I used TryParse and if it succeeded I added the result to a list. Didn't think of Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually i opt for a framework solution over a regex one, but in your case regex makes for the most 'elegant' solution:

```
var str = "AD 123 (+45) AS 6.7(+8%)";

var doubles = new List<double>();
foreach (var item in Regex.Matches(str, @"(\d|\.)+"))
{
    doubles.Add(double.Parse(item.ToString()));
}

//doubles = [123, 45, 6.7, 8]
```

I used `(\d|\.)+`, which matches any digit or dot.  Works for your current input.

Comment: @Wilsu Sure thing.  Honestly I'm not sure why you got downvoted so bad.  You gave a problem and an attempt at a solution.  Seems like people just see `-2` and jump on the bandwagon sometimes.

Comment: I don't really care actually. I'm here for information, not reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through checking if the characters is a number or the decimal separator and keep track of the beginning and end of each number.

```
string stuff = "AD 123 (+45) AS 6.7(+8%)";

List<double> numbers = new List<double>();

int numberStart = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(stuff[i])
        || stuff[i].ToString() == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
    {
        if (numberStart == -1)
        {
            numberStart = i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (numberStart != -1)
        {
            numbers.Add(double.Parse(stuff.Substring(numberStart, i - numberStart)));
        }
        numberStart = -1;
    }
}

if (numberStart != -1)
{
    numbers.Add(double.Parse(stuff.Substring(numberStart)));
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers));
```

Will output

> 123,45,6.7,8

The only issue here is that it's not handling the possibility of multiple decimal separators or thousand separators.